# Increase date by 1

Tags: mysql

I have a query that fetch whole year record and sums up the count.The query is as follows

```
select count(*) as t, m.machine1
from sap_prod_data s
left join sap_machine_speed m on s.mch_desc = m.machine 
where year(s.proddate) = '2016'
and m.machine1 in ('KBA','NewsLine','O-36','M-36','F-36','O-30','F-30')
and s.total_down_time>30
and s.plant IN('bla','bla')
and (
    select print_start_tm
    from sap_prod_data
    where year(proddate) = '2016' and edition = s.edition
    order by print_start_tm desc limit 1
)
```

i get the perfect result for this. If i add datetime range at the with 1 day add interval it shows 0 records. Like this

```
select count(*) as t, m.machine1
from sap_prod_data s
left join sap_machine_speed m on s.mch_desc = m.machine
where year(s.proddate) = '2016'
and m.machine1 in ('bla','bla')
and s.total_down_time>30
and s.plantIN('bla')
and (
    select print_start_tm
    from sap_prod_data
    where proddate = '".$yesterday."' and edition = s.edition
    order by print_start_tm desc limit 1
) between 's.proddate 22:30:00'
          and 'DATE_ADD(s.proddate,INTERVAL 1 DAY) 02:30:00'
```

So is this above solution possible in Mysql.?

Comment: Try changing 's.proddate 22:30:00' to ADDTIME(proddate,22:30:00')

Comment: @Lennart no its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in this line:

```
 between 's.proddate 22:30:00'
          and 'DATE_ADD(s.proddate,INTERVAL 1 DAY) 02:30:00'
```

It should be:

```
select count(*) as t, m.machine1
from sap_prod_data s
left join sap_machine_speed m on s.mch_desc = m.machine
where year(s.proddate) = '2016'
and m.machine1 in ('bla','bla')
and s.total_down_time>30
and s.plantIN('bla')
and (
    select print_start_tm
    from sap_prod_data
    where proddate = '".$yesterday."' and edition = s.edition
    order by print_start_tm desc limit 1
) between CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(s.proddate,"%Y-%m-%d"),' 22:30:00') 
          and DATE_ADD(s.proddate,INTERVAL '1:02:30:00' DAY_SECOND)
```

Comment: I'd probably replace the `CONCAT` bit with `DATE_ADD(s.proddate,INTERVAL '22:30:00' HOUR_SECOND)` as both a cleaner way and a more consistent one with the other expression.

Comment: I have changed "s.proddate" to proper  date format for the safty reason .i.e if "s.proddate" is = '2016-02-10 10:12:42' it will add '22:30:00', which is not required

Comment: i gotta solution for this. I  was getting 1270 Error in mysql, so problem solved using the query i have posted.

Comment: I see, but then you'll have the same issue with the `DATE_ADD` in your query. Anyway, that's resolved easily using `DATE()`: `DATE_ADD(DATE(s.proddate),INTERVAL '22:30:00' HOUR_SECOND)`.